# Add filename to attachment page url

Tags: customization, php, permalinks, images, urls

I wan to change my premalinks to attachment pages from `http://example.com/.../attachemnt/something` to `http://example.com/.../attachemnt/something/something.jpg`

It should simply add filename but with nice url, I tried with add query arg() but this builds url query like `?name=something.jpg`.

Is there solution to achieve this without hard coding anything to wordpress?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Would it not be easier to reference the actual file? eg. `wp-content/uploads/2010/12/yourfile.jpg` if you want the file name and extension in the URL..

Comment: While the question is technically interesting, won't displaying image-like URL for HTML page be confusing?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't require a Wordpress modification per se, but if you prefer to do it that way, here is a decent tutorial: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-page-redirect. Some people would, however, prefer to do this via the .htaccess file, here is a quick guide on how to do redirects that way: http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/#red1.